# creating cubes with for loop in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, cubes

I'm trying to create cubes in OpenGL/glut using a for loop but as yet I only get an overflow.

here's the code to create the cube with textures:

```
void Cubes1Class::render()
{
    for (int face = 0; face < 6; face++)
    {
        if (face < 1)
        {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texHandle[1]);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            for (int vert = 0; vert <= 4; vert++)
            {
                glVertex3fv(VertsZ[FacesZ[face][vert]]);
                glTexCoord2f(TexZ[vert][0], TexZ[vert][1]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texHandle[0]);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            for (int vert = 0; vert <= 4; vert++)
            {
                glVertex3fv(VertsZ[FacesZ[face][vert]]);
                glTexCoord2f(TexZ[vert][0], TexZ[vert][1]);
            }
        }
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

and this is where I try to render it with a for loop:

```
CubesClass::CubesClass(int num)   // constructor
{
    numOfCubes = 3;
    for (int i=0; i<numOfCubes; i++)
    {
        lst[i]=new Cubes1Class();
    }
}

void CubesClass::render()
{
    int x = 0;
    numOfCubes = 3;

    for (x = 0; x < numOfCubes; x++)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(0.0, x, 0.0);
            lst[x]->render();
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

Any idea?

EDIT:

The cubes render fine without the for loop if I just render then translate then render then translate etc. 
These are the arrays:

```
static GLfloat VertsZ[8][3] = {
  { -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 }, /* 0 left top rear */
  {  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 }, /* 1 right top rear */
  {  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 }, /* 2 right bottom rear */
  { -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 }, /* 3 left bottom rear */
  { -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 }, /* 4 left top front */
  {  0.5,  0.5,  0.5 }, /* 5 right top front */
  {  0.5, -0.5,  0.5 }, /* 6 right bottom front */
  { -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 }  /* 7 left bottom front */
};

static GLuint FacesZ[6][4] = {
  7, 6, 5, 4,   /* front */
  6, 2, 1, 5,   /* right */
  3, 7, 4, 0,   /* left */
  5, 1, 0, 4,   /* top */
  7, 6, 2, 3,   /* bottom */
  2, 3, 0, 1    /* rear */
};

static GLfloat TexZ[4][2] = {
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0
};
```

the cubes1Class is empty currently

Comment: What do you mean by "get an overflow"?

Comment: Can you show us the `VertsZ`, `FacesZ` and `TexZ` arrays? Or better yet, can you give the full declaration and implementation of the `CubesClass` and `Cubes1Class` classes?

Comment: As soon as I render it, it the glut window stops and in the cmd window it prints openGL error:Stack overflow.

Comment: when do you get overflow? after first render or after few frames? My bet is that you got some bad/missing constructor/destructor/operator= somewhere or missing `glPopMatrix` ... your class hierarchy for cubes is a bit misleading .... have you tried breakpoints? to see if you ever execute the `glPopMatrix` ...  Also check the camera setting code there can be missing glPOP too ...

Comment: The overflow was as soon as I rendered the cubes. I started the whole thing from scratch copying everything little by little and it ran fine. Still not sure what produced the overflow but it's gone now. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It works now not sure why it just didn't 
sorry if I wasted time :/

here's the end code:

```
#include "Cubes.h"
#include "bitmap.h"

static GLfloat VertsZ[8][3] = {
{ -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 }, /* 0 left top rear */
{  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 },   /* 1 right top rear */
{  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 },   /* 2 right bottom rear */
{ -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 },   /* 3 left bottom rear */
{ -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 },   /* 4 left top front */
{  0.5,  0.5,  0.5 },   /* 5 right top front */
{  0.5, -0.5,  0.5 },   /* 6 right bottom front */
{ -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 }    /* 7 left bottom front */
};

static GLuint FacesZ[6][4] = {
7, 6, 5, 4, /* front */
6, 2, 1, 5, /* right */
3, 7, 4, 0, /* left */
5, 1, 0, 4, /* top */
7, 6, 2, 3, /* bottom */
2, 3, 0, 1  /* rear */
};

static GLfloat NormalsZ[6][3] = {
0, 0, 1,    /* front */
1, 0, 0,    /* right */
-1, 0, 0,   /* left */
0, 1, 0,    /* top */
0, -1, 0, /* bottom */
0, 0, -1   /* rear */
};

static GLfloat TexZ[4][2] = {
{0.0, 0.0 },
{0.0, 1.0 },
{1.0, 1.0 },
{1.0, 0.0 }
};

static CBitmap *bmp0; // the texture 
static CBitmap *bmp1; // the texture 
static GLuint texHandle[2]; // the open gl texture handle

void readTextureFile()
{
bmp0= new CBitmap("metal.bmp");
printf("bmp size %d %d\n",bmp0->GetWidth(),bmp0->GetHeight());

bmp1= new CBitmap("starTexture3.bmp");
printf("bmp size %d %d\n",bmp1->GetWidth(),bmp1->GetHeight());

glGenTextures(2, &texHandle[0]);

// Texture handle will be bound to the BMP bitmap data just
// as it was read in...
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texHandle[0]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
       0,                              // Mipmap level 0
       3,                              // 3 bytes [R,G,B] per pixel
       bmp0->GetWidth(),   // width of bitmap
       bmp0->GetHeight(),  // height of bitmap
       0,                              // no border pixels
       GL_RGBA,                     // bitmap pixel format
       GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,               // format for GL to store it
       bmp0->GetBits()               // pointer to the pixel data
 );  

 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texHandle[1]);
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
       0,                              // Mipmap level 0
       3,                              // 3 bytes [R,G,B] per pixel
       bmp1->GetWidth(),   // width of bitmap
       bmp1->GetHeight(),  // height of bitmap
       0,                              // no border pixels
       GL_RGBA,                     // bitmap pixel format
       GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,               // format for GL to store it
       bmp1->GetBits()               // pointer to the pixel data
);

}
// ------------------------- Cubes1Class -----------------------------

Cubes1Class::Cubes1Class() // constructor
{

}

void Cubes1Class::render()
{
for (int face = 0; face < 6; face++)
{
    if (face < 1)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texHandle[1]);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        for (int vert = 0; vert <= 4; vert++)
        {
            glTexCoord2f(TexZ[vert][0], TexZ[vert][1]);
            glVertex3fv(VertsZ[FacesZ[face][vert]]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texHandle[0]);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        for (int vert = 0; vert <= 4; vert++)
        {
            glTexCoord2f(TexZ[vert][0], TexZ[vert][1]);
            glVertex3fv(VertsZ[FacesZ[face][vert]]);
        }
    }
    glEnd();


}
}

// ------------------------- CubesClass -----------------------------

//Cubes1Class *lst[MAX_NUM_CUBES]; // the cubes
//GLfloat angle[MAX_NUM_CUBES]; // the cubes rotations

CubesClass::CubesClass(int num)   // constructor
{
    numOfCubes = 4;
    for (int i=0; i<numOfCubes; i++)
    {
        lst[i]=new Cubes1Class();
    }
}

void CubesClass::render()  // draw it
{
    for (int i=0; i<numOfCubes; i++)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(0.0, i, 0.0);

            lst[i]->render();
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```